# Acid-Base Tag - Work Needed

Tags: discussion, tags

The current [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base) tag only defines acidity/basicity in Bronsted/Lowry terms. I propose the creation of a Lewis-acidity/basicity tag.

> An acid is either a proton donor, or an electron-pair acceptor. A base is either a proton acceptor, or an electron-pair donor. In aqueous solution, acids have a pH less than 7 and bases have a pH greater than 7.

Also, what's up with the arbitrary reference to the pH of 7? Let's not perpetuate the misconception that any neutral solution has a pH of 7. That's only for neutral solutions at a temperature of 25 degrees Celsius. The only condition for solution neutrality is A(hydronium ion) = A(hydroxide ion) or more simply, [hydronium ion] = [hydroxide ion].

Answer (score 3):

Rather than create a whole new tag, I would encourage you (or anyone else, time permitting) to specify all of that information in the tag wiki.  Leave the original definition (Brønstead, sorry, rusty), but elaborate on the limitations of it, etc.  It doesn't need to be a book's worth, but everyone would be able to benefit from it.

Were we to gain a substantial body of questions which would benefit from separate tags, we can certainly revisit it.

Comment: You mean leave the Bronsted acid definition?

Comment: @Dissenter Yes, sorry.  Haven't used those terms in a while.

Comment: @Dissenter I have modified the tag wiki to include a wider range/ scope of questions.